# How can I draw things using this Java GUI API?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, drawstring

My instructor has defined [this](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61b/fa08/docs/ucb-docs/ucb/gui/package-summary.html) API for graphics.

It's very simple but I've spent an hour or two now trying to figure out how to make simple Graphics manipulations show up.

So I have a class T which extends TopLevel and it is my main frame. I also have a Pad P which extends Pad and here's the body of its paintComponent method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("Hello", 0, 0);
    g.fill(new Rectangle(5, 5));
    repaint(); //(Probably don't need)
}
```

I then call `T.add(P)`, (I also do `T.addButton(..)` and `T.display(true)`. When I run the application I see an empty canvas with the button I've created.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you specifying the layout of your pad within your top frame?

Comment: I've tried it with empty params and this: `new LayoutSpec("width", 20, "height", 20);`

Comment: 1) *"..T which extends TopFrame"*  What is a `TopFrame`?  I see only [`TopLevel`](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61b/fa08/docs/ucb-docs/ucb/gui/TopLevel.html) 2) None of the 4 classes extends any AWT or Swing component.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My apologies, meant TopLevel. You are correct about none of the 4 classes AWT or Swing, I believe those details are meant to be encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing text is not as simple as you think.

The y position represents the font's base line (the point where most text sits.  There is also a decent line, where characters that sit below the base line will extended to (characters like 'g' and 'p').

The font also has a ascent.  This is the "height" of a typically character above the base line (excluding, obviously, the descent)

[image]

*Image from [Measuring Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)*

In order to paint the text properly, you must ALWAYS add the ascent to the y position...

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
g.drawString("Hello", 0, fm.getAscent());
```

You can also lose the `repaint` call, this will cause the repaint manager to (eventally) call the `paint` method of you component, over and over and over...again...

In Swing, `Graphics` is typically set up so that the color is the components foreground color.  You may want to try changing the color just to be sure.

Try using something like `g.setColor(Color.RED);` before trying to paint anything.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about text MadProgrammer; I'll certainly remember that. But at this point, it's about getting anything to paint.

I also had the hunch about my things being painted in the same color as the background so I couldn't see them, but changing the color didn't change anything.

Comment: Stupid idea, but, add a `System.out.println("painting");` call inside the `paintComponent` method, just to be sure it's begin called

Answer (score 0):

T.setVisible(true); // after construction

Comment: Where do you see this method? I think that's what `T.display(true).` is doing, but I don't see a `setVisible`.